# How to get full command executed using sh module?

Tags: python

I ran into an error while executing one of our devops scripts. The script uses the sh package (for executing common unix commands, [pypi link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sh)). However, the commands that are executed are truncated in the messages printed by sh. How can I see the whole command that was executed?

example:

```
import sh   
sh.ssh(host,
       'rsync -av {src} {dst}'.format(src=src,
                                      dst=dst),
       _out=sys.stdout
   )
```

Produces output like:

```
INFO:sh.command:<Command '/bin/ssh dbw@ny...(77 more)' call_args {'bg': False, 'timeo...(522 more)>: starting process
```

I'd like to see the full command executed, and all of the call_args.

Answer (score 1):

`sh.ssh` returns an `sh.RunningCommand` object, which you can query to find the call args and the cmd:

```
import sh   
a=sh.ssh(host,
       'rsync -av {src} {dst}'.format(src=src,
                                      dst=dst),
       _out=sys.stdout
   )
print(a.cmd)
print(a.call_args)
```

Answer (score 0):

After peeking into the source code, it looks like this is controlled by the `max_len` parameter of the `friendly_truncate` function, so one option may be to edit the `sh.py` code directly and set a higher int value:

https://github.com/amoffat/sh/blob/master/sh.py#L424

https://github.com/amoffat/sh/blob/master/sh.py#L425

Or, possibly just remove points where that function is called.