# Python's sh module - how to show the constructed command string

Tags: python, sh

I'm using [`sh` module](https://github.com/amoffat/sh) in Python3.

I'd like to see the final command string that is being issued to the shell.

The answer seems be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35642765/220949), but I'd like to see the command before executing it.

Is this possible? How can I do this?

Comment: The module doesn't generate command strings for everything it does; it merely implements the same *functionality* for many.

Comment: I realized a workaround, see my answer...

Answer (score 1):

It was easier than expected.

To print the constructed command, you can do:

`print(sh.echo.YOURCOMMAND)`

Or better still:

```
my_command = sh.my_command.bake(['my', 'options'])

# print my_command as a string
print(my_command)

# execute my_command
my_command()
```

`sh` is great !

Comment: Ah, the old `echo` prefix trick when testing an alias or bash script :-)